# I need to highlight the nodes dynamically when click external button in vis.js

Tags: vis.js

I need to highlight the nodes dynamically when click external button in vis.js. Based on node highlight I need to show the some graphical oriented chat

Please refer the image

[image]

Please help for this. Advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

In terms of highlighting nodes, if you don't really require drawing anything around the node, and are just interested in highlighting the node in some fashion, you may want to take a look at the 'neighboorhood highlight' example in the vis.js documentation (http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/neighbourhoodHighlight.html), which actually 'highlights' nodes by graying out everything else. This could possibly be combined with the handling of the rollover events for the highlighted nodes, which could display what you're interested in for each particular node.

Answer (score 1):

Also someone can change node color with `update` method:

```
nodes.update([{id: 1, color: {background: '#RRGGBB'}}]);
// nodes is of type vis.DataSet
```

Example (thanks to [example from vis.js documentation](http://visjs.org/examples/network/data/datasets.html)):

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const nodes = new vis.DataSet([{id: 1, label: 'Node'}]);
const data = {nodes};
const options = {};
const network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const randomHexRGB = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255 * 255 * 255)).toString(16);
  const colorNew = {background: randomHexRGB};
  nodes.update([{id: 1, color: colorNew}]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Change node color</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```